# Unable to format a CF card

Tags: filesystems, gparted

I have a compact flash card formatted to FAT16. I am unable to format it to any other file system. I used GParted to format the card to ext2 for example, after I do that, the file system becomes unknown to GParted! <s>I ran fsck on the card and it returned a dirty bit to be deleted. Do I deleted this dirty bit?</s>
'sudo fsck /dev/sdb1' output now:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
dosfsck 3.0.16, 01 Mar 2013, FAT32, LFN
/dev/sdb1: 1 files, 0/61366 clusters
```

Comment: Since it is a fresh partition and you don't have any data to loose, you might as well do whatever fsck says (`fsck -y` will spare you the questions).  BTW: If you can run `e2fsck` on the partition, you do have a real filesystem and you can ignore my answer.  **I think you should add more details to your question though,** such as a cut n' paste of the fsck command you actually ran and the output it produced.

Answer (score 0):

I think there maybe some misleading information around about how to *format* a partition with GParted, such as this ["How to Format a USB Drive in Ubuntu Using GParted" page.](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17001/how-to-format-a-usb-drive-in-ubuntu-using-gparted/) **<- I don't think that will actually format the partition** in the sense of creating a filesystem, it just sets the partition type in the partition table on the device.

To actually be able to use the partition as that type, a filesystem must be created on it.  GParted can do that, but it seems to me you must do it explicitly ([see here](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-format-partition)).

To re-iterate: there is a difference between creating a partition and setting the type of filesystem it is intended to contain and actually formatting a partition with a specific type of filesystem.  You must do both in order to have a usable partition.

Comment: I don't get you, I think the two links you provided instruct to the same task, there is no difference in the steps mentioned. Please have another look at my question, I have a CF card formatted to FAT 16, when I use GParted to format it to another file system, it becomes unknown. Running fsck returns a dirty bit, do I delete it or not?

Comment: It seems to me the first one never explicitly formats the partition.  According to the second one (official documentation), you are supposed to select *Partition->Format* from a drop down menu.  **I could be wrong,** but I think unless you have done that explicitly, it did not actually format the filesystem.  It just sets the type in the partition table, which is usually all a partition tool (e.g., parted, to which Gparted is a GUI front-end) does.